# Sliders episode- teaser happens in a world overrun with lawyers

Tags: episode-identification, sliders

This was before the producers decided to kill off Professor Arturo- in the beginning the sliders are on an alternate earth where an overwhelmingly large number of the people are litigation-happy lawyers; consequently film critics fear to say what they really think of the latest Pauley Shore movie, getting food at a burger joint involves more red tape than applying for a passport, and Rembrandt is told his apology for bumping into someone is an "admission of guilt", setting himself up for a frivolous lawsuit- yeah, they were lucky to get off that world as soon as they did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Season 2 Episode 11 [Greatfellas](https://www.blueroofproductions.com/sliders/sliders-season-2-episode-10-greatfellas)

> We quickly learn that they are on a world full of lawyers where everyone is so terrified of being sued that almost nothing gets done. They try and order a burger but need different forms of ID and insurance. It's funny but also a bit sad because we aren't that far from being there ourselves. Remy accidently bumps into an old lady who almost imminently tries to sue him and an attorney runs up to Remy and gives him his card, wanting to defend him in the lawsuit. The gang laughs as they open the vortex and leave this world behind.

Found with a search for `sliders episode lawsuits`